I'm developing an app with flutter, what size should the splash image be?
I'm developing an app with Flutter.
I'm using flutter_native_splash right now,
I'm trying to create a splash screen with a background image.
At this time, what size of the splash image should be specified?
Can I implement two splash screens, iOS and Android, with one image?

You can use one image to implement a splash screen for both iOS and Android. When you use a flutter_native_splash package, then you have to configure it in the pubspec.yaml file, which is the place where you need to configure this package.

Thank you.
I understood that I had to use one image.
But if you use background_image, I don't know what size of background_image should be.
Also, as far as I know, the image is the same image as the icon in the center of the splash,
Branding was understood by the image at the bottom.
If so, how should I specify the image size of the image and branding?

You can see the required resolution for the background image in this video. The requirement for Android 11 and below is at 4:50 and 6:20 for Android 12 and above. However, according to this video, there is not support for background images for Android 12 and above.
